# Convert JS Array to VBA Array. How to call array var

Tags: javascript, arrays, vba, excel

I am working in VBA. I want to convert JS array to VBA array. I almost there. I am filling Array: "Classarray" successfully! However I have a problem with calling a function which will convert it to VBA Array. The function which I use is here:

```
Dim SortedArray As Variant
Dim jsObj As New ScriptControl
jsObj.Language = "JScript"    
With jsObj
  .AddCode _
    "var classArray = new Array();" & ArrayString & _
    "function setArray(ja) {" & _
    "var dict = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.Dictionary');" & _
    "for (var i=0;i < ja.length; i++ )dict.add(i,ja[i]);" & _
    "return dict.items();}"
  SortedArray = .Run("setArray", classArray)
End With
```

The problem is in line "SortedArray = .Run("setArray",classArray). I have got error "Error:5007 'lenght' is null or not an object" In debug mode when point on classarray it display "empty", but it isn't! See attached .jpg. Could you tell me what am I doing worng with .Run function?? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Because the property is `length`, not  `lenght`

Comment: You haven't shown us the `Run()` function, so how can we tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: .Run is a method of jsObj.

Comment: Ok I wrote lenght here, but as you can see in the code it is written properly length. I think the the problem is the function doesn't see classarray... = Length is null

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it. In function I replaced "ja" with "classarray".Sorry for posting a question which I answered by myself,  I tried to find solution whole day. 
Anyway, may someone will use this code for his own purpose.